# What is the .NET Core way of storing application settings?

Tags: .net-core, settings

I'm developing a cross-platform (win/mac/linux) application and I'm looking to store my application state. What is the .NET Core recommended way of doing this?

I've dug through the documentation and the closest thing I found was [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet?view=vs-2019), which is aimed at Visual Studio/.NET Framework (and I'm on VS Code).

Comment: can you define what state meant?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways,

1. **ONLY For Localhost**

> Simply stash them in your appsettings.json or as environment
>   variables.

**For Staging / Production,**

2. **Azure Key Vault**

By utilising **Azure Key Vault** and the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault NuGet Package, you will be able to stash configurations for your projects in the best way possible in the actual environment.

You then simply inject it in,

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
 WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
 .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
 {
     var root = config.Build();
     config.AddAzureKeyVault(
        $”https://{root["KeyVault:Vault"]}.vault.azure.net/",
        root[“KeyVault:ClientId”],
        root[“KeyVault:ClientSecret”]);
 })
 .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Although you still have to stash those 3 variables in, Azure has Azure AD to enforce access only to specified Applications. Thus, you need to register an application under the Azure AD in order for this to work. There are also restrictive features that will help you sandbox Azure Key Vault further.

3. **Existing Vault Storages**

Last but not least, the last way is to utilise existing vault storage options like HashiCorp. Libraries like https://github.com/rajanadar/VaultSharp will help you to implement it quickly and effectively. This is suitable for you if you primarily use a non-Azure provider for your servers.

Comment: `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault` has been **deprecated**. You should now use [Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets)

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration), you can use `appsettings.json`, which is generated and referenced within the new project template in `dotnet new` command

Comment: I'm not using ASP.NET though, I'm writing a GUI .NET application - using the cross-platform QML for the UI, since no Windows UI solutions are crossplatform.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ConfigurationBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbuilder?view=aspnetcore-2.2) from the [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/)

Although the docs are for ASP Core, you should be able to use them in your regular .Net Core app.

Create settings.json:

```
{
    "mysetting": "value",
}
```

And use it:

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("settings.json")
    .Build();

// get the values from the settings.json
var mySetting = configuration["mysetting"];
Console.WriteLine(mySetting);
```

Comment: How did you change settings at runtime then save back to file?